# converting int var to string var with unassigned local variable error

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to convert an int var to a string var for use in a .txt file.  i am coming up with a "unassigned local variable error".  I have looked thru other questions but i don't see what i am missing.  I have been able to convert int var to a string var before, i am not really sure where i am going wrong.  If you could also give me the theory with the solution it would be most helpfull

```
        int sbntmsk;
        if (RBSBtn.Checked)
        {
            sbntmsk = 29;

        }
        if (BTSBtn.Checked)
        {
            sbntmsk = 30;
        }

        string subntmsk;
        subntmsk = sbntmsk.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler has no way to know if your checkboxes will be checked at runtime and so it complains because there is a possibility that the variable `sbntmsk` reaches the point where you try to convert it to a string without having a value assigned.

To fix the message declare and initialize `sbntmsk` with  (or whatever default value you like)

```
int sbntmsk = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a default value for the integer.  For example, what would you expect to be in the string if neither button was checked?

Comment: ok, i set the initial int to 0 and it resolved my issue.  I was making the assumption that the var would be initialized with a 0 value automatically.  Thank you for the Socratic approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use strings?

```
var sbntmsk = String.Empty;
    if (RBSBtn.Checked)
    {
        sbntmsk = "29";

    }
    if (BTSBtn.Checked)
    {
        sbntmsk = "30";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach:

```
int sbntmsk;
if (RBSBtn.Checked)
{
    sbntmsk = 29;
}
else if (BTSBtn.Checked)   // Notice the ELSE - IF
{
    sbntmsk = 30;
}
else
{
    sbntmsk = 0;  // a default value
}

string subntmsk = String.Empty;   // initialize with empty
subntmsk = sbntmsk.ToString();
```

Since using multiple checkboxes you are assigning to a same variable so no need to check all `IF` blocks. Also, using this way you have a possibility to define an 'ELSE' block at the end.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @otterbaub, have a look at this option too.